# How to get all emails?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, gmail-api

I want to get all emails from my account Google Apps for Work and fill a Google Sheets with the columns ID (column A) and Subject (Column B).

I did it with Google Apps Script, but for limits I can only retrieve 500 registers. I can't get more.

Is possible to get all the emails and put its values in a Google Sheets?

[image]

Update:

```
function getMail(){
var myspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxx');
var mysheet = myspreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

var start = 0;
var max = 500;
var count =0;
var row = mysheet.getLastRow()+1
while(count < 7) 
{

var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start , max);
var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads); 
var froms = [];
messages.get
  for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
{
   froms.push([messages[i][0].getId(),messages[i][0].getSubject()]);
}

  mysheet.getRange(mysheet.getLastRow()+1,1,threads.length,2).setValues(froms);

start =  start + 501;
count++;
}
}
```

Greetings,

Comment: can you update with your code? you should be able to pull more than 500 requests. did you get an error message?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I updated my post. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that should resolve your use case.

Keep in mind, there are still limitations one cannot exceed, you can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas?hl=en). For example, `getInboxThreads()` **will fail when the size of all threads is too large for the system to handle.** This is most likely what happened in your solution.

Instead, try to use `getInboxThreads(start, max)` this will retrieves a range of Inbox threads irrespective of labels. So, the code should now look something like this assuming you have 500+ emails. It is not elegant but it works.

```
function getMail(){
 var myspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
 var mysheet = myspreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

 var start = 0;
 var max = 99;
 var count =0;
 var row = mysheet.getLastRow()+1
 while(count < 7) 
 {

   var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start , max);
   var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads); 
   var froms = [];
    messages.get
      for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
    {
       froms.push([messages[i][0].getId(),messages[i][0].getSubject()]);
    }

    mysheet.getRange(mysheet.getLastRow()+1,1,threads.length,2).setValues(froms);

    start =  start + 100;
    count++;
    }
}
```

Reminder: Script runtime cannot exceed more than six minutes, if so the script will throw an exception.

Hope this helps and Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your idea improves my code, but I can't get all the emails. In average, the code retrieves 3000 threads. The Script Runtime  only execute less than 2 minutes and the process ends. Do you know another way to get all emails? I see that Google Apps Script is not the solution.

Comment: Hmm... I was able to retrieve more than 3000s threads. Was there an error message? Make sure you update the while condition and try again.

Comment: Well I retrieve 3500 threads. The message is "Result access too long. Result truncated". I will update my post in few seconds. The execution ends in 3 minutes (no six)

Answer (score 1):

My answer may be a bit late, however someone like me looking for the same topic may be useful...
Considering that the `getTreads()` method, today only allows a maximum size of 500 "Treads", my solution was the following...

```
const mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("here-your-id-sheet");
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(<mySheet>);
var Emails = label.getThreads();

while ( Emails.length > 0 ){
       Emails.forEach(cadena =>{
             const counterEmailsTread = cadena.getMessageCount();
             for (i=0; i < counter; i++){
                   const Email = cadena.getMessages()[i];
                   const entryDate = correo.getDate();
                   const emailBody = correo.getPlainBody();
                   const sender= correo.getFrom();
                     ......................................
             }
        mySheet.appendRow([entryDate, sender, emailBody])
        cadena.moveToArchive()
       }
      Emails = label.getThreads();
}
```

This algorithm retrieved all my emails, in my case it was 975 and it never stopped me until it was finished.

Every time my algorithm gets the information I need and makes it safe, I move that email to the archive.

After it finishes looping through the first 500 emails, I update the total number of emails again to continue or exit the `while(){}` loop